# How to stop bootstrap 4 carousel automatic sliding in mobile using JavaScript or any

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to stop my carousel to auto slide for mobile devices only. Can You please help me out from this query. I found some related questions in this portal but those are not working for me. Please suggest the answer. The below example is the sample bootstrap carousel code.
I'm trying to stop my carousel to auto slide for mobile devices only. Can You please help me out from this query. I found some related questions in this portal but those are not working for me. Please suggest the answer. The below example is the sample bootstrap carousel code.

```js
<script>
        
        // set breakpoint width
var BP = 362;

// start carousel
$('.carousel').carousel({ interval: (window.innerWidth<BP)?false:500 });

// if user rotates phone orientation | window resite
$(window).on('resize', function(ev){
  if( window.innerWidth < BP ){ 
    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: false });
  } else {
    $('.carousel').carousel({ interval: 500 });
  }
})
    
    </script>
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .carousel's pause and cycle to do this.. as shown below.

```js
// set breakpoint width
var BP = 362;

// start carousel
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: (window.innerWidth < BP) ? false : 500
});

// if user rotates phone orientation | window resite
$(window).on('resize', function(ev) {
  if (window.innerWidth < BP) {
    $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
  } else {
    $('.carousel').carousel('cycle');
  }
})
```

```css
/* Make the image fully responsive */

.carousel-inner img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
        <p>We had such a great time in LA!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Chicago</h3>
        <p>Thank you, Chicago!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>New York</h3>
        <p>We love the Big Apple!</p>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```